# SQL Server Query Plan creation in SSMS vs Application Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following scenario:

After a database deployment we have a .Net application server that is attempting to execute a stored procedure.

The timeout on the application is 30 seconds. When the application first attempts to execute the stored proc an attempt is made to create a new query plan but this takes longer than 30 seconds and the application has many timeouts. My experience with this is that if the stored procedure is run manually(with representative data inputs) from SSMS the first time it runs it takes about 1-2 minutes, a plan gets generated and then the application then runs smoothly.

I work with a third party company and there is s DBA there who is claiming the following:

"*Manually invoking this stored procedure will create a plan that is specific to the connection properties used (SSMS), the plan generated would not be used when the procedure is invoked by an application server.*"

Is this correct? It seems like a poor design if query plan used was linked to connection properties? Is there a difference between a query plan created if you run the stored procedure manually in SSMS vs when it is executed by an application?

If so, What is the optimal way to resolve this issue? Is increase the timeout the only option?

Comment: That depends on your SP, I suppose. The DBA might be right if your SP executes non-parametrised dynamic SQL (so injects the values of parameters instead). I suggest having a look at [Execution Plan Basics](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) and looking at the "Execution Plan Reuse" section which discusses exactly what you're looking at. Grant has also written some great books on Execution Plans; the latest can be downloaded (for **free**) [here](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/books/sql-server-execution-plans-third-edition-by-grant-fritchey/).

Comment: It's not a poor design. The ANSI_NULL setting changes how records are matched and obviously, the execution plans. This has nothing to do with what you describe though. The *first* time you run any query the server will have to load the data from disk. Subsequent calls will read the data from the cache.  Compiling an execution plan doesn't take 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Larnu. I was reading that link when you replied :) The proc takes in an Id,startdate,enddate and has no dynamic sql. I agree that the plan may need to be recompiled but does it matter to the application  if the original plan is created in SSMS or application?

Comment: You should be more concerned with the stored procedure's performance. Why does it take 2 minutes, especially when it's meant to be called from an application? Unless it works on a lot of data (dozens of millions of rows at least), there's a lot of room for improvement

Comment: @ChrisWedgwood post the query in the question itself. You're asking people to guess without any information. `ANSI NULL` is an obvious difference with a huge impact

Comment: *"Compiling an execution plan doesn't take 30 seconds"* although I agree, it shouldn't @PanagiotisKanavos, I will admit I have seen queries where the data engine does take about that length of time to compile a Execution plan for the first run. When i have though, those queries are 1,000's of lines long and full of problems like non-SARGable clauses, reference 10's of objects, etc.

Comment: The stored procedure(once a plan is generated) runs on average in 50ms. So performance is not an issue. @PanagiotisKanavos you are right that none of the data is cached on the first run so it is spending time going to disk. If the query times out then the next attempt suffers from the same issue. So thank you are right the plan is generated but the data is not cached. So I think if the cache was warmed after deployment then this would resolve the issue

Comment: The DBA is correct about possibility of different query plans. But a query plan creating is not an issue this case, that process takes some milliseconds. I'm sure cold buffer cache is the problem here. Once data loaded to the buffer cache after the first execution, next runs will be executed fast.

Comment: @ChrisWedgwood you haven't posted any information about the query, data sizes or how frequently this query runs so you're forcing everyone to guess. Caching shouldn't be an issue with an efficient query. Batch processing queries run infrequently, in the background, so delays don't matter so much.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos just chill man. I was basically saying thank you for your help. Thank you all for taking the time to respond. I am clear in my mind now what I need to do.